# Routing GET request to 'index' action with optional :sort parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Struggling with my first rails application as part of Edx' SaaS class. Stuck with a presumably fairly basic routing issue.

Search, trial & error has only gotten me the modest attempt below, so I'm now giving stackoverflow my first shot.

The task is to make the 'Title' column of a 'Movies' table sortable upon clicking the header. So far, I've added the 'link_to' .. 'movie_path...' piece marked bold below.

```
%h1 All Movies
%table#movies
  %thead
    %tr
      %th= link_to "Movie Title", movie_path(:sort => "title")
      %th Rating
      %th Release Date
      %th More Info
  %tbody
  ...
```

My routes.rb file only has the auto-generated routes based on `resources :movies`. 
To process the 'sort' option, I've change the basic 'index' method of the MoviesController as follows:

```
def index
  sort = params[:sort]
  @movies = Movie.find(:all, **:order => "title"**) **if :sort == "title"**
end
```

Now I'm getting this error message:

```
Started GET "/movies" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-27 14:58:55 -0600
  Processing by MoviesController#index as HTML
Rendered movies/index.html.haml within layouts/application (1.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 20ms

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"movies"}):
    4: %table#movies
    5:   %thead
    6:     %tr
    7:       %th#title_header= link_to "Movie Title", movie_path
    8:       %th Rating
    9:       %th Release Date
    10:       %th More Info
  app/views/movies/index.html.haml:7:in `_app_views_movies_index_html_haml__237103960__639242128'
```

Question(s):

- Should I define a separate method 'sort' rather than including the 'sort' option in `index`?
- In either case, how to properly route the request?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace `movie_path` with `movies_path` in your view.

Comment: devil & the detail.. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a great class! I see you were paying attention when they said to ask if you can't figure it out yourself.

As the comment suggested, you need `movies_path`, but there is still another problem with your code.

You currently set a `sort` variable, but then you are checking against `:sort` which is not a variable but a symbol - basically a constant.

Also when you put the `if` at the end of the line, it affects the entire line. So as you have it right now you will never assign `@movies`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Geoff. Great class indeed. Got it working in the meantime after fixing your points and a couple others..